# What are the names of seven heavens and hells in Arabic script?

Tags: jannah, names, jahannam

The names of seven heavens and hells in Arabic.

I know a few of them. Hell I know only one which is for Muslims.

What about Christians, Jews, pretenders, magicians and idol worshipers?

*Please  give names in Arabic only if possible in  script.*

Answer (score 4):

The names of seven heavens including:

> دارالسلام  /  دارالجلال /   جنت المأوی  /   جنت خلد  /   جنه العدن  / 
>   جنه الفردوس  /   جنت نعیم،
>
> Dar al-Salam (Abode of Peace),
>
> Dar al-Jalal (Abode of Glory),
>
> Jannatul Mava (Garden of Refuge),
>
> Jannatul Khuld (Garden of Eternity),
>
> Jannatul Adan (Garden of Eden),
>
> Jannatul Firdous (Garden of Paradise),
>
> Jannatul Naeem (Garden of Bliss) (or Delight)
>
> Those are considered as the names for the seven paradises which have been
>   discussed in tafsir and hadith books.
>
> اعانة الطالبین، ج 4، ص 385.

---

In regard to seven hell, as you said:

> Hell I know only one for Muslims it is

I found relatively a similar issue that based on the mentioned issue there could be the first floor of the hell for that group of the apostle of Allah (The Ummah of the Prophet) who are sinners (according to what I found as a related matter.)
Ultimately it can be declared that the other floors would be for others such as ... as you termed.

In regard to the seven hells (as you inquired for their names in Arabic script), including:

> 1:جحیم
>
> 2:لظی
>
> 3.سقر
>
> 4:الحطمه
>
> 5:هاویه
>
> 6:السعیر
>
> 7:جهنم

**References:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1915)
- [www.porseman.org](http://www.porseman.org/q/show.aspx?id=99864)